# What new tools or technologies has SE created or contributed to?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, technology

What new tools or technologies has the Stack Exchange network released? I'm talking about tools/tech related to software, integration, etc...

By "created or contributed to" I imply significant development and resources used to implement and distribute.

Related: [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Comment: I'm confused, what exactly is the purpose of this question? What makes it so different from the other one?

Comment: Am asking has the stack exchange produced useable applied tech through its q and a.

Comment: This isn't a lot to go on.

Comment: As in "Has SE released - either commercially or Open Source - any of the software it created?"

Comment: Dapper.  Also, this question makes me itch.

Comment: @Bart yes, has SE released or contributed in a significant way to the development?

Comment: @Won't I hear you are itching to answer? I look forward to your input.

Comment: @animuson: would it clarify the question if I removed the link?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) Simple SQL object mapper for ADO.NET
- [Protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) It's mainly Marc's personal project, but I think he worked on it for SE too
- [Booksleeve](http://code.google.com/p/booksleeve/) Redis bindings
- [bamboojoint](http://code.google.com/p/bamboojoint/)
  A JavaScript renderer that creates Go game diagrams from SL markup
- [MarkdownSharp](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/introducing-markdownsharp/)
- [PageDown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/)
- [Donations to open source projects they use](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/stack-overflow-gives-back/)

Found a [blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchange-open-source-projects/) which lists a few more:

Comment: I'm pretty sure I forgot an open source project, where they paid the original developer to add some features they needed.

Comment: Indeed, [HAProxy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/stack-overflow-sponsors-haproxy/).

Comment: Very good answer can we expect updates to your answer in time?